# IEnumerable<T>.Count() returns 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a variable of type `IEnumerable` and if I call `Count()` method on it before foreach loop then it returns the correct count but after the foreach loop it returns 0. Why is that?

**[UPDATE]**

According to the given answers, I found out that my `IEnumerable` is kind of one-shot thing. So I've attached my code because I already converted it to a list and returned as `IEnumerable`. So where I'm doing it wrong?

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<WorkItem>> Get(int[] workItemIds)
{
    return await context.WorkItems
                        .Where(it => workItemIds.Contains(it.Id))
                        .ToListAsync();
}

private async Task<int> ApproveOrRejectWorkItems(IEnumerable<WorkItem> workItems, int status)
{
    // var workItemsToBeUpdated = workItems.Count();
    workItems = workItems.Where(it => it.StatusId == (int)WorkItemStatus.Submitted);
    foreach (var workItem in workItems)
    {
        workItem.StatusId = status;
    }

    // here value becomes 0

    await _unitOfWork.WorkItemRepository.Update(workItems);

    return workItems.Count();
}
```

Comment: Presumably you can only iterate the source once.

Comment: what type of IEnumerable<T> ?

Comment: In that case you might want to use `ToList` to get the results into a list that will not change each time you iterate (unless you explicitly change it)

Comment: If you're passing the result of `Get()` into `ApproveOrRejectWorkItems()`, I don't see how the count could change. You're materializing the result of the query when you call `.ToListAsync()`, so the count shouldn't be able to change. Can you add the result of `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(workItems.GetType().FullName)` to your question (it will print to the "Output" window)?

Comment: @Llama Here's the output `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MyProject.Core.Models.WorkItem, Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]`

Comment: Can you show how `Get()` and `ApproveOrRejectWorkItems()` go together? I wonder if you have a situation like [this](https://rextester.com/KDXY96651) where you're filtering the resultant `List<WorkItem>` on the status?

Comment: @Llama Yes I was filtering, I removed it from the code I thought it would not be the problem. I've updated my code you can check now. So why it is the problem? Isn't the underlying implementation still a List?

Comment: Yes, but each time you iterate an enumerable, it goes back to the source to get the information. You're changing the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for clarifying that you were filtering the list after materializing it in the `Get()` method.

Your issue is that LINQ is a view. So if you iterate an `IEnumerable` twice, it will go through the source items twice, applying any filters, projections, etc. to the source items. This means that by changing the source items, the enumerable will yield different items the second time you iterate through it because those items no longer match the filter.

I would suggest you modify the method to be like this:

```
private async Task<int> ApproveOrRejectWorkItems(IEnumerable<WorkItem> workItems, int status)
{
    var workItemsToBeUpdated = workItems.Count();

    foreach (var workItem in workItems.Where(it => it.StatusId == (int)WorkItemStatus.Submitted))
    {
        workItem.StatusId = status;
    }

    await _unitOfWork.WorkItemRepository.Update(workItems);

    return workItems.Count();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely dealing with one of two scenarios:

## Outside circumstances change between enumerations

Please consider the following scenario:

```
var badRecords = repository.GetBadRecords(); //returns IEnumerable<T>
if(badRecords.Count() > n) 
{
  repository.DeleteBadRecords();
}

foreach( var badRecords in badRecords ) 
// This enumeration goes to the db again and selects 0 records because we just deleted them. 
{ 
  Log(badRecord);
};
```

The solution is to `.ToList()` early;

## Single use generator

This is similar but slightly different, we're dealing with code that by design allows just one iteration.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetAllNumbers(List<int> availableNumbers) {
    while(availableNumbers.Count > 0) 
    {
        var x = availableNumbers[0];
        availableNumbers.RemoveAt(0);
        yield return x;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var numbers = GetAllNumbers(new List<int>{1,2,3});
    Console.WriteLine(numbers.Count()); // 3
    Console.WriteLine(numbers.Count()); // 0

    numbers = GetAllNumbers(new List<int>{1,2,3}).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(numbers.Count()); // 3
    Console.WriteLine(numbers.Count()); // 3
}
```

---

#### Resharper's *Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable* warning

BTW. Resharper has a dedicated warning for this: [Code Inspection: Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/PossibleMultipleEnumeration.html)